# How to create a leaderboard query with kinesis analytics

Tags: amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm trying to do a proof of concept for a real time leaderboard using kinesis analytics and am trying to use their getting started example, tumbling time period example with the demo stock ticker data stream.  However I get the error `Leading column in ORDER BY must be monotonic` when I try to simulate a leaderboard sorting by price.

```
SELECT from and INSERT into like a TABLE
    -- PUMP: an entity used to continuously 'SELECT ... FROM' a source STREAM, and INSERT SQL results into an output STREAM
    -- Create output stream, which can be used to send to a destination
    CREATE OR REPLACE STREAM "DESTINATION_SQL_STREAM" (ticker_symbol VARCHAR(4), price REAL);
    -- Create a pump which continuously selects from a source stream (SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001)
    -- performs an aggregate count that is grouped by columns ticker over a 10-second tumbling window
    -- and inserts into output stream (DESTINATION_SQL_STREAM)
    CREATE OR REPLACE  PUMP "STREAM_PUMP" AS INSERT INTO "DESTINATION_SQL_STREAM"
    -- Aggregate function COUNT|AVG|MAX|MIN|SUM|STDDEV_POP|STDDEV_SAMP|VAR_POP|VAR_SAMP)
    SELECT STREAM  ticker_symbol, price
    FROM "SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001"
    ORDER BY price desc
    -- Uses a 10-second tumbling time window
    GROUP BY ticker_symbol, price, FLOOR(("SOURCE_SQL_STREAM_001".ROWTIME - TIMESTAMP '1970-01-01 00:00:00') SECOND / 10 TO SECOND);
```

Answer (score 0):

[According to the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisanalytics/latest/sqlref/sql-reference-order-by-clause.html), the ORDER BY must be time-based in addition to monotonic:

> A streaming query can use ORDER BY if its leading expression is
>   time-based and monotonic

In your case, you appear to be calculating the timestamp in your GROUP BY, but you'll have to either add the same calculation to the ORDER BY (or perhaps figure out a way to do it in the SELECT and give it a column alias).